# No clang package for 16.04 seems to contain pp-trace

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, clang

I'd like to use Clang's `pp-trace` tool (on a Kubuntu 16.04 machine)

I already have `clang` installed. Typing in `pp-trace` gives me:

```
The program 'pp-trace' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt install clang
```

but ...

```
$ # apt-get install clang
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
clang is already the newest version (1:3.8-33ubuntu3.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 103 not upgraded.
```

and `apt-cache search pp-trace`, `apt-cache search pptrace` also don't yield anything. And, actually,

```
# ls -la /usr/bin/pp-trace
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 jun 21 08:33 /usr/bin/pp-trace -> ../lib/llvm-3.8/bin/pp-trace
# ls -la /usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/pp-trace
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/pp-trace': No such file or directory
```

Uninstalling and re-insalling clang-3.8 did not help. What can I do?

Comment: What does `dpkg -l clang` report?  Does it agree with http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/clang/filelist?

Comment: @muru: If you meant `dpkg -L`, then yes, it agrees. If you meant `dpkg -l`, I've added that.

Comment: sorry, `-L`, yes. Since it does, I suppose you should see if `/usr/bin/pp-trace` is missing and if so, reinstall the clang package.

Comment: @muru: Serves me right for automating the agreement check rather than actually looking at the list... apparently, my `/usr/bin/pp-trace` is a dead symlink to `../lib/llvm-3.8/bin/pp-trace`.

Comment: @muru: I uninstalled and reinstalled for the same effect

Comment: looks like a bug. The clang-3.8 should have that file, but it doesn't, and other clang-3.* versions do: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=Pp-trace&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=any Maybe file a bug

Comment: 3.8 debian/ubuntu source has a pp-trace makefile but no longer an install path (may have earlier in 3.8 resulting in broken symlink, there is a debian report on that.  current ubuntu 3.8 does not.) 3.9 debian/ubuntu source no longer has a pp-trace makefile. Maybe use 3.7

Comment: @doug: the 3.7 package doesn't come with pp-trace either.

Comment: Does here - /usr/lib/llvm-3.7/bin/pp-trace

Comment: @doug: But does it really? I went to [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com), downloaded [llvm-3.7 for Xenial Xerus](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/llvm-3.7/download) (direct link to the DEB: [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/llvm-3.7/download) - and there's no `pp-trace` in there. Same for 3.8.

Comment: @muru: See my last comment. No, they don't.

Comment: It's installed here. /usr/bin/pp-trace-3.7 links to /usr/lib/llvm-3.7/bin/pp-trace. Ex - `ls /usr/lib/llvm-3.7/bin |grep pp-` returns `pp-trace`

Comment: @doug: Packages website says otherwise.

Comment: @doug clang-3.x: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=Pp-trace&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=any

Comment: Please take closer look - http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/clang-3.7/filelist

Comment: And i386 - http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/clang-3.7/filelist

Answer (score 0):

From looking at packages.ubuntu.org, and specifically - the [llvm-3.8 package for Xenial Xerus on AMD64](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/llvm-3.8/download), it seems the file is just missing.

This [Debian bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=839909) may be relevant.